# r - B Spline plotting

Tags: r, spline

I have a panel data with 8 variables (each one having some missings). I estimated the following semiparametric model with fixed effects in this form using the spline function:

```
library(npreg)
library(splines)
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
library(npregfast)
library(haven)
library(effects)
require(car)

model <- lm(lnA ~ lnB  + lnC + lnD  + lnE + lnF + bs(lnX, knots = 3) + bs(lnZ, knots = 3) + factor(id) - 1, 
  data=mydata)
```

where `lnA-F` are parametric estimates and lnX and lnZ are estimated nonparametrically through the spline function.

Now, I would try to plot the levels of `lnX`and `lnZ` (separately and/or together) on the predicted values of lnA (with the corresponding confidence intervals).

This is my attempt (which didn't work though):

```
plot(Effect(focal.predictors = c("lnX","lnZ")),     
   mod=model,      type = "response",       
   ylab="predicted lnA",
   main="non parametric estimate of lnX and lnZ on lnA")
```

I also tried this and it worked (it provides me a fitted line), although I am not sure it is correct:

```
ggplot(data = mydata) +
geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = lnX, y = model$fitted.values), level=0.90, color = 'red') + 
xlab("lnX") +
ylab("fitted lnA") +
ggtitle("Model")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.